# Zoom Webhook Validation using Python

Tags: python, validation, fastapi, webhooks, zoom-sdk

I've make an endpoint for Zoom to validate the webhook URL, but this is the output
`Unauthorized request to Zoom Webhook sample.`

this is my python code:

```py
@router.post('/webhook')
async def webhook(request: Request):
    headers = dict(request.headers)
    body = await request.json()
    
    print(headers)
    print(body)
    # construct the message string
    message = f"v0:{headers['x-zm-request-timestamp']}:{body}"
    # hash the message string with your Webhook Secret Token and prepend the version semantic
    hash_for_verify = hmac.new(ZOOM_SECRET_TOKEN.encode(), message.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    signature = f"v0={hash_for_verify}"

    # validating the request came from Zoom
    if headers['x-zm-signature'] == signature:

        # Zoom validating you control the webhook endpoint
        if body['event'] == 'endpoint.url_validation':
            hash_for_validate = hmac.new(ZOOM_SECRET_TOKEN.encode(), body['payload']['plainToken'].encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

            response = {
                'message': {
                    'plainToken': body['payload']['plainToken'],
                    'encryptedToken': hash_for_validate
                },
                'status': 200
            }

            print(response['message'])
            return response['message']
        else:
            response = {'message': 'Authorized request to Zoom Webhook sample.', 'status': 200}

            print(response['message'])
            return response

            # business logic here, example make API request to Zoom or 3rd party

    else:
        response = {'message': 'Unauthorized request to Zoom Webhook sample.', 'status': 401}

        print(response['message'])
        return response
```

I've tried to change the hash encoding but same problem

Comment: I am currently having the same issue. Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: for whoever is facing this issue, I was able to resolve it by using request.data when constructing the message instead of using request.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this the final code. I've fix it by myself

```
@router.post('/webhook')
async def webhook(request: Request):
    headers = dict(request.headers)
    body = await request.json()
    print(headers)
    print(body)

    if 'payload' in body and 'plainToken' in body['payload']:
        secret_token = ZOOM_SECRET_TOKEN.encode("utf-8")
        plaintoken = body['payload']['plainToken']
        mess = plaintoken.encode("utf-8")
        has = hmac.new(secret_token, mess, hashlib.sha256).digest()
        hexmessage = has.hex()

        response = {
            'message': {
                'plainToken': plaintoken,
                'encryptedToken': hexmessage
            }
        }
        print(response['message'])
        return response['message']
    else:
        return {'error': 'Invalid payload'}
```